# MySQL-Update inserted auto increment primary key to custom value

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

When I insert a new row, an auto increment ID will be saved like 1,2,3..
I need to custom it using a Trigger so it will be saved like 20171,20172,20173..

Comment: Seems odd, but ok.  What do you want to 10th value in that series to be, 201710?

Comment: Thank you for the comment.
it's ok to be 2017257  :)

Comment: I want to make it like 2017+the_old_id

Comment: Ok, gotcha.  And now you may have a reason for needing that.  I was just hoping to point out that the order of the index won't be grouped by years unless you use characters.  Which you could do.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get it, but I believe that can be done using a Trigger, right?

Comment: Sure, using a BEFORE INSERT trigger and you set the id value.  I think you might want separate columns for the id's and the year, though.  Would that be an option?

Comment: I think I don't need a separate column, I want to replace the index 1,2,..  with itself but after the year. 20171, 20172...

Answer (score 1):

This trigger would do this.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET NEW.id = (
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),IFNULL(MAX(CAST(ids.id AS UNSIGNED))+1,1))
    FROM (
        SELECT RIGHT(t.id,LENGTH(t.id)-4) AS id
        FROM test t
        WHERE LEFT(t.id,4) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    ) ids
);

END
```

But there are many reason you would not want to.  This will get exponentially more expensive as rows are inserted, and provides no viable sorting etc.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will test it as soon as possible when I reach office